# Add and Delete users from a MVC pryect

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, jsonresult

I am working on a cshtml page to delete and create users for the company's users (task that was done manually in the SQL Server). I have added the following @html.ActionLink for the btn to perform the action:

```
<tr>
     <td>@item.Nombre </td>
     <td>@item.Documento </td>
     <td>@item.Email</td>
     <td>@item.EsAdmin</td>
     <td>
          @{
                   if (@ViewBag.EsAdministrador)
                   {                                                                    
                         @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id = item.Id });                                                                                   
                   }
              }                             
    </td>
```

Now, in the EmpleadoController, the Action to Delete looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete()
{
      try
      {
            EmpleadoModel EmpleadoModel = new EmpleadoModel();
            UserSerializer userSerializer = new UserSerializer();
            var userPrincipal = userSerializer.UserRole(Request, 
            ((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity).Ticket.UserData);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
        }
}
```

So far the btn doesn't delete the user, any idea what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the `item.Id` being passed as a parameter in the controller action. Either remove it from the `ActionLink` if you're not using it or add that parameter to the controller action.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where you suggest I should place it? I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Assuming `id` is of type int, then you can add it in here;
`public ActionResult Delete(int id)`